# how can we get flutter firebase OTP read and autofill without any package or plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

**how can we get flutter firebase OTP read and autofill without any package or plugin?**
**don't want to use plugin like alt_sms_autofill,sms_autofill..etc.**

Answer (score -1):

1 - Add firebase to your program

2 - In firebase console active phone authentication

3 - Provide your SHA-1 and SHA-256 in SHA certificate fingerprints

4 - Add google-services.json to your app

5 - Go to Google Cloud console and select your firebase project
then go to Apis & services -> Enable Apis & services -> Search for
Android Device Verification and enable it

6 - Write the code for firebase otp genration in flutter

7 - Done your otp will read and autofill